# Resource registry condition to differentiate authors and users

Tags: plone

I am looking for a Plone resource registry condition(TALES expression) that can pick the difference between a logged in content author (with editing rights) and a regular logged in site user (with no editing rights)… can anyone help?

Comment: Before upgrading to Plone 4.3 we were using: 
  
  `python:member is not None and request.get('X-Pseudo-Logged-In', 'no') == 'no'`  
  
  I have played with Products.CMFCore.Expression and also Products.ResourceRegistries but i cant figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative could be using the context state view:

```
context/@@plone_context_state/is_editable
```

Comment: That is much more elegant and less process intensive as well i assume... cheers for that. I tested and works fine even in distributed setup.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to do the trick:

`expression="python:portal['portal_membership'].checkPermission('Modify portal content', context)"`

Comment: That should do it. I think you may be able to use just `checkPermission`, because I think it's exposed.

The "X-Pseudo-Logged-In" bit is specific to your implementation (I remember it vaguely ;-) and is set in a web server to deal with some specific caching logic. You may want to make sure this works in a cached/scaled environment. Drop me an email if that's not clear.

Comment: Any idea where there is doco on this? I searched for examples or a write up on TALES expressions that will work in the _context_ of a resource registry expression and came up empty handed. Given there is no visibility what variables are available to the user at the UI, I eventually had to stick break points in zope packages to see what was happening... this situation happens too often in Plone/Zope imo. A more useable UI would have a description and example expressions available in context alongside the user facing control.